# Create Records with Linq to SQLite via DbLinq

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, dblinq

I have (after some significant effort) gotten DbLinq working with the latest build of Mono on OS X.

Has anybody successfulyl created database entities via DbLinq/Sqlite?

For example, I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE UserType (
    id integer primary key,
    description text )
```

I have generated my *.cs file and am using the following code to attempt to create a new UserType entry:

```
UserType newUserType = new UserType();
newUserType.id = null // Attempting to get SQLite to increment
newUserType.description = "Administrator";

db.UserType.InsertOnSubmit(newUserType);

db.SubmitChanges();
```

The call to SubmitChanges is throwing an exception about invalid syntax **specifically related to @** (I'm guessing in a parameterized query to do the insert). It looks like the code being generated is SQL Server specific. Is there a fix or flag I'm missing, or is inserting records through DbLinq to SQLite not supported?

Comment: I am trying to generate .cs code with dbmetal. I get an exception. Could you please post a sample of how you generated the .cs(code) file from a sqlite database?

Comment: @Jitesh Can you please tell me how you got the cs and dbml file using DbMetal? if possible answer my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396143/creating-linq-to-sqlite-dbml-from-dblinq-source-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that when using DbLinq, you need to modify the DB Connection string so Mono's System.Data.Linq knows which DB provider to use when generating its SQL code.

Old:

```
SqliteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite");
```

New:

```
SqliteConnection("DbLinqProvider=Sqlite;Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite");
```

It's as simple as that.

Comment: Where is the SqliteConnection class located?

Comment: Ok, to answer my own question, you need to reference the System.Data.SQLite.DLL library