# creating Linq to sqlite dbml from DbLinq source code

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, sqlite

I tried to create linq-to-sqlite dbml using [DbLinq](http://dblinq2007.googlecode.com/files/DbLinq-0.19-src.zip) but in vain. 
Each time I get different type of errors. May be I'm somewhere wrong.

Can anyone tell me the step by step procedure to create the dbml file from the Dblinq source code.

Comment: A more useful link: http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/

Comment: It will probably help if you let us know what errors you are getting.

Comment: Windows Error Message: "DbMetal has stopped working". This is what i get. Check my edit also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

***Steps I followed:***

1. Downloaded the DBLinq 0.20 source code from [this Link](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/downloads/list)
2. Built it.
3. copied my database and `System.Data.SQLite.dll` file to `src\DbMetal\obj\Debug` folder
4. Used the following codes to create dbml file from db and cs file from dbml file respectively

> DbMetal /provider:Sqlite /conn "Data Source=File.db3" /dbml:File.dbml
>
> DbMetal /code:File.cs File.dbml

The procedure is well illustrated in this link -> http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a /provider:PROVIDER option to `DbMetal.exe` so that it knows what kind of database you're using, otherwise it assumes you want Microsoft SQL Server.

Furthermore, you can only use the `/dbml` or `/code` options, not both at the same time.

Try this command instead:

```
DbMetal /provider:Sqlite /conn "Data Source=myDb.db3" /code:mycode.cs /namespace:myNS
```

If that doesn't work, please file a bug at: http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/issues/list

Comment: I get this in the command prompt.......................
DbLinq Database mapping generator 2008 version 0.17.0.0
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 3.5
Distributed under the MIT licence (http://linq.to/db/license)




>>> Reading schema from DBML file 'Data Source=nwind2009.db3'
Press any key to continue . . .


my command in run_sqliteMetal is:

@echo off

bin\DbMetal /provider:Sqlite /conn "Data Source=nwind2009.db3" /dbml:mycode.dbml /namespace:myNS

pause

Comment: Please try using either 0.19 or trunk.  Alternatively, it's a bug while processing your .db3 file; please file a bug.

Comment: Still i got no help. Recently i tried 0.20. I get this error now: DbMetal: Access to the path 'G:\' is denied.

Comment: What's the full command you're using?  It seems rather odd that it would be trying to access G:\.  See also: http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/wiki/Installation

Comment: @jonp: Thanks for the help. I cleared the old copy and installed a fresh copy of dblinq and it works fine now.